# Cannot access Magento secure urls after rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, security, magento, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

On Magento, I tried to remove all references to index.php from urls, and now I am unable to access any secure pages apart from Admin.

I get an error message saying:
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
Address: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) Server at web72.secure-secure.co.uk Port 80

I was able to access all secure links successfully before I followed this guide (http://www.indianwebportal.com/remove-index-php-url-magento
) which said to do the following:
- Set Use Web Server Rewrites to YES (Magento Admin)
- Set Use secure URL Frontend to YES (Magento Admin)
- Add the following code to .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I've cleared the cache, logged out and back in, but nothings worked. I am able to access admin and all pages apart secure front end links.

Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: are you trying this on local machine? whats your stack? LAMP or WAMP?

Comment: The site is hosted online. I'm almost certain it's on Linux, if that's what you mean? The secure links all worked before I added the code above. Thanks for your message!

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel > System > General > Web > Secure

there change your base url to **https://**

If you running magento on localhost, it may not work.